# I am setting value in session variable in another page using ajax.What is the other way to send value to another page?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have multistep form in which on second page i have date input field.I want to fetch value using that date input field by setting that value in PHP variable.Remember that i Don't have submit button on 2 step I have only previous and next button on 2 step.I am using ajax for that.

```
 <input type="date" name="date" id="date" />

  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="nextnew" id="nextnew" class="next action-button" value="Next" />


  <script>
       $("#nextnew").click(function() {

             var name2 = $("#date").val();
               alert(name2);

             $.ajax({
             url:"getuser.php",
            type:"GET",
             data:"id="+name2,
              success:function(data){
             $("#detail").html(data);

               }
              });
        });  

</script>
```

On this page I have defined ajax through i am sending value to another page.

My getuser.php.

```
 <?php

 include('config.php');
     session_start();  
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
  {

$vaue=$_GET['id'];
  echo $vaue;
 $_SESSION['new22']=$_GET['id'];

  ?>
```

This problem is that I am setting value using session but the problem is that it will set only once .how i can set value using another variable and sent to main page.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Why My question is unclear.

Comment: you can set variables using cookie, also session variables can be reset many times.

Comment: I am using multistep form so I am running this ajax on next button on 2 step.If i will set session variable it will set the value till we reload the page.Can you define another method how i can set value@Sasikumar.I want set value in this page and sent to some other page.

Comment: session is the only possible know method to send value like that

Comment: Other than session is there any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello my friend please use bellow code in ajax

*data: {
                id: name2
            },*

Comment: I just not want to use session variable to sent value to another page i want some other method@Brijesh kumar.